# Saving page as .html and upload to ftp

Tags: html, file, upload, ftp, save

I allow myself to ask the question here cause I looked for what to do regarding my problem but didn't find anything helpful.

Im having a webpage where users can modify information such as text, images etc, and I would like to add a button which would save the page as an .html in its current state (reloading the pas reset everything) and upload it on a ftp so they could have access to it online.

At this point, I know how to get all the html content using js .innerHTML, and how to send a file to the ftp using php, but I don't know what to look for to generate the .html file with the innerHTML content in it.

So here I am, asking for your help to guide me toward the right direction.
Thanks a lot!

Following theCNG27's suggestion, I think now the issue comes from my php script.. Sorry about that but Im really not used to php yet.

here is the php script:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("filename.html", "w+");
fwrite($handle, $_POST['HTML']);

$dossier = 'endpoint/';
$fichier = basename($_FILES['HTML']['name']);

if(!isset($erreur))
{
 $fichier = strtr($fichier, 
      'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ', 
      'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');
 $fichier = preg_replace('/([^.a-z0-9]+)/i', '-', $fichier);
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['HTML']['tmp_name'], $dossier . $fichier))
      echo 'Upload done !';
 }
 else
 {
      echo 'Upload failed !';
 }
 }
 else
 {
 echo $erreur;
 }
 ?>
```

it says "no data received"

thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have Text (in your case the HTML code) in your javascript that you want to transfer to your php script and save it as a file!? Is that correct? If so, I would recommend this:

Since javascript is client-side and php is server-side you should send by POST.
I would use a form like this:

```
<form name="myform" action="url/to/php/script.php" method="POST">
<button type="submit">Submit!</button>
<input type="hidden" name="HTML" id="htmlsubmit" value="">
</div>
</form>
```

Now in the js-script you have to update the value of your hidden input like this:

```
document.getElementById("htmlsubmit").value = htmlcode;
```

htmlcode represents your HTML code you got through .innerHTML

Now in your PHP script you just have to receive the code and write it to a file:

```
$handle = fopen("filename.html", "w+");
fwrite($handle, $_POST['HTML']);
```

Since you already know how to upload a file to ftp via php, just do that with your file "filename.html" ;)

Hope that helps

EDIT: You edited your question and said you need help with the php script... This would be a possible complete script you could use:

```
<?php
$fname = "filename.html";
if(!isset($_POST['HTML']))
{
    echo "Error: No data received...";
}else{
    $handle = fopen($fname, "w+");
    fwrite($handle, $_POST['HTML']);
    fclose($handle);
    echo "HTML Code written to file: <a href=\"".$fname."\">".$fname."</a>";
}
?>
```

Is that all you need in your script?

Comment: I edited my question with php script. It seems that it doesn't work now. At first, the php script was made to upload picture so it may not be consistent.

Comment: Okay, your script is a little confusing to me... Is the ONLY purpose of this script to save the html code?? You are kind of handling a file upload with your script but the html code is transmitted per plain text post. not file upload. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Awesome it works! Sorry about my script.. It was working to upload file such as pictures and so on so I assumed it would be working if I managed to generate a file with the html then upload it.

Im not used to php at all yet so your help is much appreciated.
Thx!!!

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript, calling `innerHTML` on the document element will give you the markup of the page as a string, including changes made to the DOM.

```
var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Then, you could post this markup to an endpoint using AJAX. The endpoint can receive the string, save it as a html file and then upload it somewhere via FTP.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Im not familiar with AJAX but I'll look into it. The main issue here is to not know what to look for.